# How to show that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{|x|>N} |x|^3e^{-4x^2} dx=0$?

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

I have to find the following limit:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{|x|>N} |x|^3e^{-4x^2} dx=0$$
The hard part is permutting limit and integral. I do not know how to apply the monotone convergence theorem since $|x|^3e^{-4x^2}$ is not $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: $|x|^3e^{-4x^2}$ IS in $L^1$.

Comment: Maybe you mean $|x|^{-3}$ or something like that? Either way, you only need the integrand to be in $L^1(|x|>N_0)$ for some $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$ ( and hence for all $N\geq N_0$).

Comment: You could of course also just evaluate the integral: $\int x^3 e^{-4 x^2} d x = -(1+4 x^2) e^{-4 x^2}/32$.